# How to use `md5sum` to process `$1` of `awk`?

Tags: awk, md5sum

`test` file as example:

```
cat <<'EOF'> test
/boot/efi/EFI/debian/grubx64.efi root root 700 1625230722
/boot/efi/EFI/debian/mmx64.efi root root 700 1625230722
/boot/efi/EFI/debian/shimx64.efi root root 700 1625230722
/boot/grub/fonts/unicode.pf2 root root 644 1625230723
EOF
```

I plan to add one more column to `test` file,the value of new added column depends on the first column(`md5sum --binary($1)`),such as `md5sum --binary /boot/efi/EFI/debian/grubx64.efi`.

My script is `awk '{ cmd = "md5sum --binary" close(cmd) $(NF+1) = (cmd($1)); print }' test > test_new` but got error as below:

```
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near =
```

I am new to `awk`,what's the problem?

Comment: Statements in awk must be separated by semicolon or newline characters. There is no statement separator before the ´close` statement, and nont after it.

Comment: @user1934428: That is not the only problem.

Comment: @anubhava : It's the problem for the **syntax error**. If you place a semicolon after `close(cmd)`, **this** syntax error goes away. It doesn't mean that the script is working afterwards, but for this aspect, you have already posted a good answer. I just wanted to answer the literal question of the OP, because she also wanted to know the cause of this error message.

Comment: @rowboat,checksum of a file referenced by $1.

Comment: `md5sum` is a command. Awk is a tool to manipulate text, not a tool to sequence calls to commands. A shell is a tool to sequence calls to commands. When you try to use awk for this you're actually doing a stack of calls `shell { awk { shell { md5sum } } }` spawning a new subshell once per input line to call md5sum whereas if you just call md5sum from shell then it's simply `shell { md5sum }`, i.e. 1 shell calling md5sum once per input line which will be faster and simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `awk` should work:

```sh
awk '{cmd = "md5sum --binary \047" $1 "\047"; 
if ((cmd | getline out) > 0) print $0, out; close(cmd)}' file.test
```

However for task like this a `bash` loop should do job better as we are calling an external program using just the first column:

```sh
while read -r col1 rest; do
   echo "$col1 $rest" "$(md5sum --binary "$col1")"
done < file.test
```

Comment: Thanks. Should I add statement separator in awk?

Comment: I tried the second method and redirect to `new` file,but got error:`while read -r col1 rest; do
   echo "$col1 $rest" "$(md5sum --binary <<< "$col1")" > file.test.new
done < file.test`

Comment: `bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
`still got above error.

Comment: You can see a [working demo here](https://ideone.com/RhTZIN)

Comment: `md5sum <<< "aaa"` works well,but `echo "$col1 $rest" "$(md5sum --binary <<< "$col1")";` output `Syntax error: redirection unexpected`.

Comment: `5.0.3(1)-release`.I guess the error caused by `sudo ./*.sh`?

Comment: `sudo...` cause error,`sudo bash ...` solve problem.

Comment: Thanks Ed for your insightful comments. I have modified my answer as your suggestions.